# woff2 and Intel XDK

Tags: cordova, local, webfonts, intel-xdk, woff2

I'm trying to use Material Icons with on my app using Intel XDK with no success.

In my tests I got to the conclusion that the woff2 file must be in a `http://` domain, and I got no success trying to load it from `file://`. So how to do it on Intel XDK? In what path should the font be to load it?

**EDIT:** Bower isn't working on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

Download the icons and fonts and make them part of your project folder (somewhere within the source directory, under the `www` folder). You may have to add some CSP rules to your `index.html` file to be able to load and read those files, but generally, if you're using standard HTML5 references that is not necessary, only if you're using XHR calls.